# How do I create a disabled icon from an enabled one

Tags: user-interface, icons, image-manipulation

I have a bunch of icons, and I need to create grayed versions of them to be used when the corresponding command is disabled. How can I do that in an easy way, preferrably using [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) since that is the only graphics program I have installed?

Comment: @casablanca: I disagree. Programming is much more than writing code, it is about problem solving. If the customer comes to you with the requirement "the icon should look disabled if it can not be used", solving that problem is "programming" in one sense.

Comment: And, as to why I want to do it, it appears that IE does not do it if having a disabled button with an image inside it.

Comment: @erikkallen: I fully understand what you're saying. If you had asked how to programatically create a disabled icon, that would be a valid question here. But asking "how do I use GIMP to do this" isn't related to programming -- you might try asking on a GIMP forum or a web design forum.

Comment: @casablanca: It sure is related to programming. I can't solve my programming problem, which is implementing the requirement "the icon should look disabled when the action can not be performed" without solving this problem first. Also, I think the solution will be interesting to many other programmers out there, as this is not exactly an uncommon requirement

Comment: @erikkallen: I believe you're confusing programming (which is just writing code) with the overall software development process, which includes, among other things, design and artwork. If you want a programming solution to your problem (one that works directly in the browser), the closest I can think of is to dim the icon by reducing the opacity (this is what even SO's editor does).

Comment: Some may agree that this question should be in other place than stack overflown, but I must say this was really helpful for me :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could try in GIMP, Colours -> Desaturate

Comment: With this approach black will remain black. Disabled icons are usually greyed out. In my opinion, [this is a better answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10078817/897326).

Answer (score 10):

My usual in GIMP is to ensure the image is in RGB mode (Image->Mode->RGB) and use Colors->Hue/Saturation, changing the Saturation down to -50 and the Lightness up to 50.

If there is a color still prominent in the disabled image, try also adjusting the Lightness up on one of the Primary Colors in the same dialog.

Comment: This works really well for black & white buttons and puts them in the gray nicely, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of documenting -If you don't have GIMP, you can use Microsoft Office (Word or PowerPoint).

1. Add the original Enabled (color) icon.
2. Go to the 'Picture Tools' menu and press on 'format' > 'Color' > 'Color Saturation = 0%'
3. Save the icon - Right mouse click - 'Save as Picture'